# C++ ReadFile, CreateProcess, Pipe Stdout redirection, doubled Output

Tags: c++, stdout, readfile

i have this piece of code :

```
        for (;;) {
            BOOL ReadSuccess = ReadFile(rdPipe, StdOutBuffer, 8192, &dwRead, NULL);

            if (strlen(StdOutBuffer) <= 0) {
                Sleep(100);
                send(sock, RECIEVE_BREAK, strlen(RECIEVE_BREAK), 0);
                break;
            }

            else if (!ReadSuccess || dwRead == 0) {
                Sleep(100);
                send(sock, RECIEVE_BREAK, strlen(RECIEVE_BREAK), 0);
                break;
            }

            else {
                send(sock, StdOutBuffer, strlen(StdOutBuffer), 0);
            }

            cout << StdOutBuffer << endl;
            cout << "\n\n\n\n";
        }
```

And i have problem with doubled output in my StdOutBuffer, for example, when i call "tasklist" i've got some parts twice.

Dont u someone know where can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

The function [`ReadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't read a null terminated c-string, but a block of (here 8192) chars without any guarantee to have a null terminator.

Therefore, calling [`strlen(StdOutBuffer)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) is not guaranteed to give any useful result. You should rather rely on `dwRead` instead.  If you read text data that might be not null terminated (in the file or, as it seems, via the pipe), you should add it yourself:

```
 StdOutBuffer[dwLen] = '\0';
```

This works even if the read fails, because the first thing `ReadFile()` does is to set the length to 0. Note that your buffer should then have a size of at least 8192+1 char.

***Why do you get the error ?*** Suppose you receive a full line of data, and that fortunately, it includes some null terminator.  You'd then process it. Suppose now that in the next iteration you'd only receive a couple of chars (e.g. just a newline):  the remaining of the buffer would not overwritten, and as you'd not have a null terminator at the end of the new bytes read, `strlen()` would cause to think there is more data to process than there is; some data would be processed a second time.